# Duplicate an existing geoserver style using gsconfig

Tags: python, geoserver, style, sld, gsconfig

I am playing around with gsconfig and trying to assign a new style on a layer I have created.
What I want to do is to actually create a new style, which is the same with an existing one.
I searched online and show that they propose to read the sld from a file:

```
with open(path_to_sld_file) as f:
   cat.create_style('newStyle', f.read(), overwrite=True)
```

Would it be possible to get the existing style from geoserver and then pass it as a variable in the "create_style" function?

f.read() returns a string so I guess it should be possible if I just pass the variable with the SLD instead of f.read().